# Inversion across a general ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.6378v1.pdf) is very useful in how it explains the mapping of any coordinates $(x,y)$ across an ellipse with the function $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

to $$\left(\frac{a^2b^2x}{a^2y^2+b^2x^2},\frac{a^2b^2y}{a^2y^2+b^2x^2}\right)$$

But what if that ellipse is a rotated one, as described [here](http://www.maa.org/external_archive/joma/Volume8/Kalman/General.html)?

I can't even figure it out if I compare it with a circle, but if anyone could help me convert $(x,y)$ to the inverted coordinates, I'd be very happy.

Comment: I think the deduction method should be the same as for the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ but a little more complicated for the calculations. Optionally, you can transform the ellipse rotated to its simplest form and then turned back to the original. Am I wrong?

Comment: hi @Ataulfo I like the idea of changing the ellipse of inversion, but I'm not really allowed to do that :( I'm also not sure of the method should be the same for the ellipse $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$. It looks like calculations are going to be more complicated, but how is the deduction method same or different?

Comment: hi @amd would it be possible if you could help? thanks!